# Can we say anything about the surjectivity of norms over reals?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

I believe we can say that any $\ell_p$-norm (restricting the codomain to the positive reals) is surjective:

Let $z\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Choose $x=ze_1=(z,0,...,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
$$||x||_p^p=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^p=|z|^p=z^p$$

i.e. $z=||x||_p$. Does this look correct?

Further, are we able to somehow generalize this result to any (restricted) arbitrary norm $||\cdot||:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (or a norm over any any normed space), and if so what would be the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any norm on any non null real or complex vector space is surjective when it’s codomain is $\mathbb R_+$. Indeed, take any non null vector $x$, then forall $\lambda \geq 0$ you have $$
||\lambda x || = \lambda ||x||$$
which shows the norm is surjective.